# Vesting terminology/terms for salary negotiation (how much is my vesting REALLY worth?)

Tags: negotiation, bonus, onboarding, vesting, stock

I'm in late stage negotiations with a new employer (current employer suddenly started going downhill, despite being a Fortune 500 company; abusive, rescinding benefits, cancelling bonuses, etc. Rather than spend money and ruining my reputation suing my employer, I'm seeking new work).

The new employer's salary is about 10% less than what I'd hoped for, but the vesting schedule sounds impressive (they're also a Fortune 500 company, indirect competitor to my current employer). Let's say, they promised:

> $80,000 of stock, [vested over 4 years, with a 1 year cliff.](https://carta.com/blog/what-is-stock-vesting/)

Now, if I have this right, the amount paid out each year would be $20,000, which I could cash out at the end of each fiscal year, i.e.:

```
Year 0 (day 0):    $0.00       ($0.00 paid to date)
Year 1 (day 365):  $20,000.00  ($20,000.00  paid to date)
Year 2 (day 730):  $20,000.00  ($40,000.00  paid to date)
Year 3 (day 1095): $20,000.00  ($60,000.00  paid to date)
Year 4 (day 1460): $20,000.00  ($80,000.00  paid to date)
Year 5 (day 1825): $20,000.00  ($100,000.00 paid to date)
Year 5 (day 2190): $20,000.00  ($120,000.00 paid to date)
```

**Question:** Now, what I'm trying to determine is if this assumption is correct, and what terminology I should be using to clarify this confusion of mine with my interviewer:

Does this basically equate to a $20,000.00 "guaranteed bonus" per year (i.e. Year 5 an onward is a flat $20,000.00 bonus per yer), or is the amount even more? **i.e. Does this vesting amount get re-awarded every 4 years, or every year?** If the latter, the bonus looks a lot more attractive, i.e.:

```
Year 0 (day 0):    $0.00       (      $0.00 paid to date) ( $80,000.00 awarded so far)
Year 1 (day 365):  $20,000.00  ( $20,000.00 paid to date) ($160,000.00 awarded so far)
Year 2 (day 730):  $40,000.00  ( $60,000.00 paid to date) ($240,000.00 awarded so far)
Year 3 (day 1095): $60,000.00  ($120,000.00 paid to date) ($320,000.00 awarded so far)
Year 4 (day 1460): $80,000.00  ($200,000.00 paid to date) ($400,000.00 awarded so far)
Year 5 (day 1825): $80,000.00  ($280,000.00 paid to date) ($480,000.00 awarded so far)
Year 6 (day 2190): $80,000.00  ($360,000.00 paid to date) ($560,000.00 awarded so far)
```

**I'm hoping** it's the latter of the two methods. Also, the latter seems to make more sense (i.e. more bonus the longer the employee is with the company, rather than a constant flat amount per year that starts on day 365). **But what terminology/question do I use/ask to confirm which of these two methods is being used?** My best guess is something like:

> Is this "$80,000.00, 4 year vest, 1 year cliff, awarded every 4 years" (i.e. method 1), versus "$80,000.00, 4 year vest, 1 year cliff, awarded every 1 year"?

The HR person currently helping me sounds like she's reading off of a script, rather than really understanding the questions I pose (maybe I'm being too technical, but I'm really trying hard to put it in layman terms without being vague). I'm wondering if I should just straight up ask "is this worth $20,000.00/year when I hit the 5 year mark, or $80,000.00/year when I hit the 5 year mark"? I don't want to "leave money on the table", but don't want to have the offer rescinded if I seem too greedy (really want to get the hell out of my current job).

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Did you ask the company what the terminology means?

Comment: Nobody here can tell you what is meant. The contract could say anything.

Comment: You may be making a few assumptions it'd be good to check--is there any guarantee of a re-award at all at any point (in my industry, there is not)?  What are these "stocks"--RSUs, stock options (each has different implications and neither will be a guaranteed 80,000 at the end of 4 years)?

Comment: Typically with vesting you get a lump sum and you own more of it as time goes on. If I offer you $100 to attend a meeting for me and it vests over 2 hours with a 30 minute cliff, you don't get anything if you don't sit in the meeting for at least 30 minutes. If you sit through 2 hours of the meeting, you get the full $100. If it vests every 30 minutes, staying at the meeting for 45 minutes gets you $25 and if you stay for 60 minutes, you get $50. You probably get 80K of stock at current market value and have to work 4 years to own all of it.

Comment: You should keep in mind that $80K of stock today is not necessarily $80K of stock next week. There's a risk that the stock could be completely worthless by the time you're fully vested in it. There's also the chance it could be worth a lot more by the time you are able to sell it. If you don't understand the financial implications, you really should talk with a financial planner to understand how that affects your finances and taxes.

Comment: Thanks @ColleenV  I've put together a spread sheet to take into account depreciation due to changes in the value of the underlying stock and inflation of the the dollar, and will keep that in mind.

Comment: @Donna Just keep in mind that no one can tell you exactly how much that stock is going to be worth in 4 years. But don't let that dissuade you. If you think the company is going to do well, a significant stock award is a good way to get wealthy. When I lived in Austin, we called the early employees of Dell "Dellionaires" because of how much money they made on their stock compensation. I strongly recommend finding a good financial planner to help you understand the risks and the benefits for you and your particular situation.

Answer (score 8):

It's this

> Year 0 (day 0):    $0.00       ($0.00 paid to date)

> Year 1 (day 365):  $20,000.00  ($20,000.00  paid to date)

> Year 2 (day 730):  $20,000.00  ($40,000.00  paid to date)

> Year 3 (day 1095): $20,000.00  ($60,000.00  paid to date)

> Year 4 (day 1460): $20,000.00  ($80,000.00  paid to date)

And then it ends. And that's it. You don't keep getting stock. You *might* get stock as part of your overall compensation package later, or you *might* not. If it isn't in the contract, then the answer is you won't get it.

Comment: Thank you. I had not considered the scenario where it's a glorified signing bonus with a ton of strings attached.

Comment: @Donna - how is it a signing bonus with a 1 year cliff?

Comment: @sevensevens To rephrase "it sounds like a crappy 'signing bonus' with a 1 year cliff and 4 year vesting period" if it doesn't renew or grow (i.e. it's basically a lump sum, promised at signing time, but doesn't continue perpetually, if it stops at the end of year 4).

Comment: @Donna - it sounds like more of a retention bonus than anything else.  I've updated my answer slightly as I'm pretty sure it's 4 years with vesting happening at the end of each year.

Comment: This is probably correct if it is an annual vesting schedule. Some companies have shorter vesting schedules and it's definitely a point that can be negotiated.

Comment: Keep in mind this is stock, not money, so it probably vests in number of shares, not dollar amounts.

Comment: @ColleenV YES. But i can only base off what OP really discussed.

Comment: This doesn't preclude additional grants and often you will get annual or other additional grants with the same vesting schedule, but yes, the initial grant as stated is 4 years and gone, $80k total.  Also keep in mind the $80k is based on current valuation and isn't guaranteed - the grant will actually say "10,000 shares at current strike price of $8" or something and then if the stock value goes up or down then of course the value of yours goes up or down.

Comment: @seven literally all sign on bonuses are effectively with a one year cliff

Answer (score 3):

**Bring these charts and ask questions using the charts.  Based on my experience you'll get 20k a year in vested stock through year 4, then 0 for year 5 (similar to chart 1).**

Based on experience, I'm betting it's chart 1 (20k a year each year) for 4 years.  Make sure you get anything after the fourth year, as the my experience suggest a total of 80k then you'll get 0 for the fifth year unless you renegotiate.

It's a quick chat with HR to clarify all of this.  I've written the example chat below to chart 2 since it's a bit more involved.  Either way, substance is the same.  It never hurts to ask.

You've already done most of the work for this.  Most people have a general understanding of vesting/cliffs, but nothing beats an example.  You can say something like

> Just want to make sure I'm understanding this correctly.  After the 1 year cliff I'm vested 20k in stock - correct? (point at that line), Then after 2 years I'm vested for 40k in stock a year - correct? (point at the next line).  For 3 years, it's 60k a year (point at line), then finally after 4 years I cap out at 80k a year in stock options (point at line).  Is all that correct?

Finally ask what happens if you leave a few days shy of your yearly anniversary.

> What happens if I leave 1 day before my 3rd year.  Will I get a
> pro-rated amount of stock, or do I always have to stay the full year?

Be sure to bring the other chart too.  My guess is chart 1 is correct.  Unless you earn several hundred thousand a year, it looks like the stock payout will be a large portion of your yearly income by year 4 using chart 2 (80k).  Even industries such as sales that have large bonus payouts, that's usually cold hard cash.  Just ask people at Enron how holding a lot of company stock worked out for them.

Comment: +1 For mentioning pro-rating. You bet that's bitten some people.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably how it will work (from personal experience):

At the beginning of the employment contract you are awarded X "virtual" shares, based on the opening/closing/average share price on that day, to the total of $80K, but you can do nothing with them, they sit in a "holding" account.

After the first year one quarter of those shares, minus the number required to cover the withholding tax, at that day's price, are transferred to a brokerage account that you designate by the broker that manages the entire scheme. You are free to do with these shares as you please.

Thrice more the event repeats, each time landing 1/4 of the original number of shares, minus those that cover the applicable tax, in your brokerage account. Then the process ends.

Comment: This is a correct definition of vested stock.  Just to add, if stock currently trading at 100$ you get 800 stocks, after a year you will be able to cash 200 stocks on their then price

if stock falls - you get less money, if stock rises you get more money